# Cannot find Symbol Error. Cannot find getSelectedItem() and setBackground() methods

Tags: java, compiler-errors, actionlistener, jcombobox

When trying to run my program I get an error because it cannot find my method.
Here is the First Error Code:

```
Error: cannot find symbol 
  symbol: method getSelectedItem()
  location: variable event of type java.awt.event.ActionEvent
```

Here is the Second Error Code:

```
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setBackground(java.awt.Color)
  location: variable x of type java.lang.Object
```

Here is the Program Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class PanelColor extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
  // Declare all instance data  (primitives and objects used) 
  private int WIDTH = 501;
  private int HEIGHT = 501;
  JPanel panelN;
  JPanel panelS;
  JPanel panelE;
  JPanel panelW;
  JPanel panelC;
  Container con; 
  JComboBox  box;
  Dimension dPN;
  Dimension dPS;
  Dimension dPE;
  Dimension dPW;
  Dimension dPC;

//constructor 
  public PanelColor(){
    super("Panel Color"); 
    con = getContentPane(); 
    con.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    panelN = new JPanel();
    panelS = new JPanel();
    panelE = new JPanel();
    panelW = new JPanel();
    panelC = new JPanel();
    dPC = new Dimension(25,25);
    dPS = new Dimension(200,200);
    dPE = new Dimension(400,200);
    dPW = new Dimension(400,200);
    dPN = new Dimension(200,200);
    panelC.setBackground(Color.RED);
    panelN.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    panelE.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    panelW.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    panelS.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
    panelC.setPreferredSize(dPC);
    panelN.setPreferredSize(dPN);
    panelE.setPreferredSize(dPE);
    panelW.setPreferredSize(dPW);
    panelS.setPreferredSize(dPS);
    box = new JComboBox();
    box.addItem("Panel North");
    box.addItem("Panel South");
    box.addItem("Panel East");
    box.addItem("Panel West");
    box.addItem("Panel Center");
    box.addActionListener(this);
    con.add(panelC, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    con.add(panelE, BorderLayout.EAST);
    con.add(panelW, BorderLayout.WEST);
    con.add(panelN, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    con.add(panelS, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    con.add(box, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
}

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    Object source = event.getSource();
    Random r = new Random();
      int  red = r.nextInt(255) + 1;
      int  green = r.nextInt(255) + 1;
      int  blue = r.nextInt(255) + 1;
      Color c = new Color(red, green, blue);
      String text = event.getSelectedItem();
      Object x = event.getSelectedItem();
      if(source == text){
        x.setBackground(c);
      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    PanelColor object = new PanelColor(); 
  }
}
```

I know there are a lot of posts about the cannot find symbol error but through all the ones I have looked at, none of them have helped me with this issue. **I want to know why it is giving me these errors? and how it can be fixed so that I know for future reference. The areas where the errors are are listed below this paragraph.** And I hope this helps others out as well if they are having a similar problem.

These are the areas that have the errors:

```
String text = event.getSelectedItem();

Object x = event.getSelectedItem();

if(source == text){
  x.setBackground(c);
}
```

Comment: If you've read all those answers, what is the meaning of a `cannot find symbol`? Don't read other answers to find a solution specifically for your issue. Understand when and why such an error occurs and you'll understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getSelectedItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem%28%29) is a method of `JComboBox` rather than `ActionEvent`

```
JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) event.getSource();
...

String text = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: Or use `event.getSource()` I suppose. But in this case, `box` is straight-forward.

Comment: But then how would I fix the setBackground method to be found?

Comment: How would I assign it to the x object?

Comment: Nevermind that, I changed the code so it does not depend upon that, thanks for the help

Comment: `String` `x` is not a component so you cant set its background color. It seems you are trying to set the color of the `JComboBox` selected item. In this case you need a [custom renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `getSelectedItem();` is define in `ActionEvent` class

You need to change it to something like:

```
String text = (String) box.getSelectedItem();
```